# How to see the details of an index in oracle NoSQL?

Tags: oracle-nosql

How to see the details of an index ?
I am executing this command to see the indexes for a table

```
sql-> SHOW INDEXES ON Persons;
indexes
idx_age
idx_areacode
idx_income
idx_state_city_income
```

but how to see the details, I cannot find a command show indexes detail

Answer (score 0):

There is no  command show indexes detail, Use the command describe

```
sql-> describe as json index idx_state_city_income on Persons;
{
"name" : "idx_state_city_income",
"type" : "secondary",
"fields" : ["address.state", "address.city", "income"]
}
```